# Webpack - Weird source map paths when using css-loader together with sass-loader

Tags: webpack, source-maps, css-loader, sass-loader

I'm using `Webpack` together with the [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader), [`sass-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) and [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) plugins to bundle styles for my application.

However, I'm seeing weird source map/resource paths using the plugins shown below:

The actual `app.scss` path is `./src/styles/app.scss`

[image: correct path]

However the source map path for the file becomes `./src/styles/src/styles/app.scss` and the absolute resource path:
`C:/Users/m51n/source/repos/source-map-path/src/styles/src/styles/app.scss` (does not exist)

[image: weird path]

I've created a sample project [here](https://github.com/jwldnr/extract-text-issue)-- using the source map example from the `sass-loader` [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#source-maps) and code from the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` docs [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#url-resolving)

Here is the `webpack.config.js` used in the above project:

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./src/styles/app.scss"
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[hash].js",
    path: path.resolve("./dist"),
    // devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: (info) => {
    //   console.log(info.resourcePath)
    //   console.log(info.absoluteResourcePath)

    //   return `webpack:///${info.resourcePath}`
    // }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: ["style-loader"],
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".scss", ".css"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html"
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "app.[contenthash].css"
    })
  ]
}
```

Expected source map path returned by the plugin in this case would be `./src/styles/app.scss` and absolute resource path as it exist on disk:
`C:/Users/m51n/source/repos/source-map-path/src/styles/app.scss`

**How can I rewrite the sample code above so that I get the desired source map paths?**

Related GitHub issue for reference:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/484

Comment: I've edited the original question to include more information related to this issue, hopefully someone has any idea how to approach my problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. Posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256634/chrome-debugger-no-domain-section-showing-duplicated-paths-after-webpack. There is way too little support for this...